# Zend Studio formats txt-sources after upload

Tags: zend-studio

Zend Studio formats txt-sources after upload.

for Ex:

```
<?php 
echo 'test';
echo 'test';
echo 'test';
?>
```

after upload this source code looks like:

```
<?php

echo 'test';

echo 'test';

echo 'test';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the **file line delimiter option**. In both Zend Studio and Eclipse it should be in Windows->Preferences->General->Workspace

If you use unix-like server you should use:

- text file encoding: **utf-8**
- new text file line delimiter: **unix**

Adjust the settings based on the server your script will woork and not on the machine you are developing.